# No module named flask, despite having it installed

Tags: python, flask

New to flask and python here. I've written a simple python app, but when i run `python app.py`, I get `ImportError: No module named flask`.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Versions:

```
Flask 1.0.2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
```

EDIT:

Typing pip freeze gives me:

```
altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
macholib==1.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
py2app==0.7.3
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
vboxapi==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Also, FWIW, if I run the app using python3 app.py, then it seems to work. Why does the command python though seem to point to  python version 2 instead of version 3? I'm wondering if I messed up installation somewhere.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `pip freeze` output?

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify the path of your python and pip using

```
which python
which pip
```

Verify if the base path is same.
Also if you are using virtualenv or pipenv then make sure to activate the instance before executing the code.

Also try to do this

```
$ python
>>> import flask
```

check if the python version is the same that you are using. you can also follow this guide for flask [Flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)

Comment: which python = `/usr/local/bin/python` and which pip = `/usr/local/bin/pip`. If I do python and then import flask, I get the same error: `ImportError: No module named flask`. Also, i'm not using virtualenv or pipenv

Comment: It is recommended that you should use a virtual environment for projects. Also using a virtual environment will further help you during the deployment process. Now https://docs.pipenv.org/install/ install pipenv and then try installing flask in that environment.